# how to read a compressed file from c# in R

Tags: c#, r

```
        String fileName = "0001.gff";
        using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
            {
                ZipArchiveEntry write_entry = archive.CreateEntry(fileName);
                using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(write_entry.Open()))
                {
                    writer.Write((Int32)1);
                    writer.Write((Int32)2);
                    writer.Write((Int32)3);
                    writer.Write((Int32)4);
                }
            }
        }
```

I have created the file `myFile` in c#, but i want to read it in R. How can i do that?

Comment: It's not clear what the format of your file is. It seems to be a binary file with fixed byte widths representing different fields, but if we don't know what they are, no-one here can help you. It's not that this can't be done in R - it can - but without giving us the file format, this is like asking us  "where is my nearest fire exit" without telling us what building you are in.

Comment: I am not good at this, but i think it is .gff

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called `read.gff` from the `ape` package the documentation says to try using

```
read.gff(file)
```

Comment: I saw this function too, but this seems to be a different `.gff` format. There is a fairly common file format called `.gff` containing genomic information, but this doesn't seem to match the type of content the OP has.